# How to get multiple users by subs (for a list of posts) from AWS cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using aws congito for user storage. Now I need to get user names and avatars for a list of user posts. But as far as a know, the listUsers api does not accept a list of subs as a filter condition. So how can I achieve this?

I have some other ideas, like syncing user information to a dynamodb by lambda trigger, or storing user name and avatar in posts database (but it's hard to update user info).

Is there a better way to get user information for a list of posts?

Comment: AWS support confirmed to me today that there is still no way to retrieve multiple users by sub in one API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until filtering by list of subs is possible, I would use multiple https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html calls with only one sub in parallel (fork join approach) and store the data in a cache (Redis would do nicely). This way, it will fetch data from Cognito only once for a user, making it very efficient after the first try.

Comment: Yes, it's good solution. And I can add expiration to keep user data relatively new. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, when the user changes the avatar, make sure to invalid that particular user’s cache. I would keep the cache available as much as possible.

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea how to identify if the user has changed something/avatar?